# Django filter local folders

Tags: python, django

I have a templatetag function that returns a Collapse menu with all folders, subfolders and images in a root directory but now I want to be able to filter which folders I get, the templatetag function recives one parameter, the root directory, and I know it should recibe a second parameter with the folder I want to get but I'm confused in this part.

in my settings.py I have this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    'D:/Users/my_user/Documents/Luis/results',
]
```

in my templatetag.py I have this:

```
from django import template  
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

import os

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def my_tag(path):
    html=''
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = os.path.join(path, file)
        if  os.path.isdir(rel):
            html += f"""<button type="button" class="collapsible">{file}</button>"""
            html +='<div class="content"><div class="row mt-2">'
            html += my_tag(rel)
            html += '</div></div>'
        else:
            html +=f'<div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch"><picture>'
            x=str(rel)[43:]
            print(x)
            html += """<img src="/static"""+"""/%s" """%(x)
            html += """ class="lazy card-img-top" width="500" height="400" """
            html += """alt="/static"""+"""/%s" """%(x)
            html +='></picture></div>'

    return mark_safe(html)
```

and in my template.html I have this:

```
{% load static files %}

    <style>
        .collapsible {
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
            color: #858E9B;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
/*        .active, .collapsible:hover {
            background-color: #555;
        }*/
        .content {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
        }.card-img-top  {
        height: 90vh !important;
        object-fit: contain;
        }
    </style>

{% my_tag 'D:/Users/my_user/Documents/Luis/results' %}


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

This is an example of the final result:

[image]

So the idea is to get a specific day, can anyone give me an idea?